# How to get the 5 most recent dates by customer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

I have a query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 and I am trying to show the 5 most recent dates for each customer.

Here is the query I use:

```
SELECT 
    Customer, Plant, ForecastDate  
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Plant, ForecastDate ORDER BY Customer DESC) AS ROW_NUM 
     FROM 
         table) AS T
WHERE 
    ROW_NUM = 1
```

Here is the output of this query:

[image: Output]

This is what I would like the output to look like:

[image: Desired output]

Here is some [Consumable sample data](https://zumbiel.weebly.com/uploads/4/1/5/0/41508101/book4.xlsx)

I am dealing with weekly forecasts that my customers give to me that changes every week or so. I upload the data into SQL Server. I am trying to to compare and contrast the Quantity to other forecast dates. This is why I want the past 5 dates. I have multiple rows on the same date but I need the past date as well because I am trying to compare past forecasts to each other.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Customer VARCHAR(3), Plant NVARCHAR(20), ForcastDate DATE)
INSERT INTO @Data (Customer, Plant, ForcastDate) VALUES
('ACA', '1100', '2022-11-21'),('ACA', '1100', '2022-11-22'),('ACA', '1100', '2022-11-23'),('ACA', '1100', '2022-11-24'),('ACA', '1100', '2022-11-25'),
('ACA', '1200', '2022-11-21'),('ACA', '1200', '2022-11-22'),('ACA', '1200', '2022-11-23'),('ACA', '1200', '2022-11-24'),('ACA', '1200', '2022-11-25'),
('ACA', '1300', '2022-11-21'),('ACA', '1300', '2022-11-22'),('ACA', '1300', '2022-11-23'),('ACA', '1300', '2022-11-24'),('ACA', '1300', '2022-11-25'),
('ACA', '1400', '2022-11-21'),('ACA', '1400', '2022-11-22'),('ACA', '1400', '2022-11-23'),('ACA', '1400', '2022-11-24'),('ACA', '1400', '2022-11-25'),
('ACA', '1500', '2022-11-21'),('ACA', '1500', '2022-11-22'),('ACA', '1500', '2022-11-23'),('ACA', '1500', '2022-11-24'),('ACA', '1500', '2022-11-25'),
('ACA', '1600', '2022-11-21'),('ACA', '1600', '2022-11-22'),('ACA', '1600', '2022-11-23'),('ACA', '1600', '2022-11-24'),('ACA', '1600', '2022-11-25'),
('ACA', '1700', '2022-11-21'),('ACA', '1700', '2022-11-22'),('ACA', '1700', '2022-11-23'),('ACA', '1700', '2022-11-24'),('ACA', '1700', '2022-11-25'),
('ACA', '1100', '2022-11-25'),('ACA', '1100', '2022-11-27'),('ACA', '1100', '2022-11-28'),('ACA', '1100', '2022-11-29'),('ACA', '1100', '2022-11-30'),
('ACA', '1200', '2022-11-25'),('ACA', '1200', '2022-11-27'),('ACA', '1200', '2022-11-28'),('ACA', '1200', '2022-11-29'),('ACA', '1200', '2022-11-30'),
('ACA', '1300', '2022-11-25'),('ACA', '1300', '2022-11-27'),('ACA', '1300', '2022-11-28'),('ACA', '1300', '2022-11-29'),('ACA', '1300', '2022-11-30'),
('ACA', '1400', '2022-11-25'),('ACA', '1400', '2022-11-27'),('ACA', '1400', '2022-11-28'),('ACA', '1400', '2022-11-29'),('ACA', '1400', '2022-11-30'),
('ACA', '1500', '2022-11-25'),('ACA', '1500', '2022-11-27'),('ACA', '1500', '2022-11-28'),('ACA', '1500', '2022-11-29'),('ACA', '1500', '2022-11-30'),
('ACA', '1600', '2022-11-25'),('ACA', '1600', '2022-11-27'),('ACA', '1600', '2022-11-28'),('ACA', '1600', '2022-11-29'),('ACA', '1600', '2022-11-30'),
('ACA', '1700', '2022-11-25'),('ACA', '1700', '2022-11-27'),('ACA', '1700', '2022-11-28'),('ACA', '1700', '2022-11-29'),('ACA', '1700', '2022-11-30')
```

This is just some sample data in a table variable for portability.

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
       (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, Plant ORDER BY ForcastDate DESC) AS rn
          FROM @Data
       ) a
 WHERE rn <= 5
```

I wasn't sure if you wanted the most recent five days per plant, or just per customer. This is per customer and plant.

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
       (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY ForcastDate DESC) AS rn
          FROM @Data
       ) a
 WHERE rn <= 5
```

This is per customer. Note how the PARTITION BY only contains `Customer` now.

Comment: This code was very helpful and I figured out how to get the answer I was looking for. I needed to convert the table to a view to get rid of the multiple rows that had the same dates.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by using a view. That way it removed the multiple rows that had the same dates. Here is that code I used:

```
SELECT Customer, Plant, ForecastDate
  FROM 
       (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, Plant ORDER BY ForecastDate DESC) AS rn
          FROM View
       ) a
WHERE rn <= 5
order by Customer,Plant,ForecastDate desc
```